# Generate com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode from string rawValue result

Tags: android, barcode, google-vision

I am using google vision for barcode scanning. I want to keep the history of every scanned result so i am storing 'format', 'rawValue' in to sqlite database. So when I want to display the history item again, I want to conver this 'rawValue" into 'com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode' object so that I can get the values directly.

So is there any way to do so ? where we pass 'rawValue' and get 'com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode' object ?

Please help me if anybody knows because I am not able to find any hint or example of it.

Comment: did u got any solution?

Comment: @saty No, I think generating a barcode or qrcode is not possible using vision API, it only designed to scan the barcode or qrcode. If you want to generate the, you can use zxing library.